# How many requests can mongodb handle before sharding is necessary?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

Does anybody know (from personal experience or official documentation) how many concurrent requests can a single MongoDb server handle before sharding is advised?

Comment: This would be based entirely on the class/type of hardware, OS, the data, types of queries, ....

Comment: I agree with @WiredPrairie , there is no factual answer to this question; there are too many unknowns which are dependant upon your scenario. I mean you could have a collection which is terabytes big handling millions of requests a day and still not need sharding

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If your working set exceeds the RAM you can afford for a single server, or your disk I/O requirements exceed what you can provide on a single server, or (less likely) your CPU requirements exceed what you can get on one server, then you'll need to shard. All these depend tremendously on your specific workload. See http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/faq/storage/#what-is-the-working-set

Answer (score 1):

One factor is hardware. Although for this you have replica sets. They reduce the load from the master server by answering read-only queries with replicated data. Another option would be memcaching for very frequent and repetitive queries, which would be even faster.

A factor for whether sharding is necessary is the data size & variation. When you have a wide range of varying data you need to access, which would render a server's cache uneffective by distributing the access to the data to the wide range, then you would consider using sharding. Off-loading work is merely a side-effect of this.